# How is Flask-Login's request_loader related to user_loader?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I apologize in advance for asking a rather cryptic question.  However, I did not understand it despite going through a lot of material. It would be great if you could shed some light on this.

What is the purpose of a request_loader in flask-login?  How does it interact with the user_loader decorator?

If I am using a token based authentication system (I am planning on sending the token to my angularJS front end, storing the token there and sending that token in the authorization-token header), will I need a request_loader or will a user_loader (where I check the auth header and see if the user exists) suffice?

Comment: I am interested in doing the same thing

Comment: "I am planning on sending the token to my angularJS front end, storing the token there and sending that token in the authorization-token header"

I am interested in doing the same thing! Can you clarify how you use(d) request_loader to achieve this?

Does Angular's $http automatically use the same cookies as other browser requests? Do we need to do the "sending the token to my angularJS front end" part? My concern is that the session id may be sent in a different header or parameter (which is why I might need request_loader) - but won't a logged-in browser still automatically send it?

Comment: Hi Zach, Sorry for the delayed response.  From what I understand, you don't actually need to have both user and request loaders.  A user loader is very simple, it checks the user_id that is attributed to the session and checks if that user_id exists in your user database and authenticates.  A request loader checks the request authorizationheader and does the same authentication.  So for most applications that have any sort of user session management, you won't need request loader. You wont have to send any tokens... Flask and angular js manage those automatically with user_loader

Comment: Hi galeej - I have found a solution that I think is even more slick. I will post it as its own answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Flask-Login [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#custom-login-using-request-loader):

> Sometimes you want to login users without using cookies, such as using
>   header values or an api key passed as a query argument. In these cases,
>   you should use the **request_loader** callback. This callback should
>   behave the same as your **user_loader** callback, except that it accepts
>   the Flask request instead of a user_id.

So, to answer your question, they both serve the same function for Flask-Login. They are both used to load the user. `request_loader`, however, is appropriate for custom logins.

Here's a great tutorial I found that utilizes `request_loader` to take advantage of token based authentication (The post is not my own, I'm merely sharing the link): http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/minimal-flask-login-example.html

Answer (score 2):

I need to make this clear.
This is the reason why you shoud use `request_loader` with flask_login.

There will be a lot of `@login_required` from flask_login used in your api to guard the request access.
You need to make a request to **pass the check of auth**.

And there will be a lot of `current_user` imported from flask_login,
Your app need to use them to let the request **act as the identity of the `current_user`**.

There are two ways to achieve the above with flask_login.

- Using `user_loader` makes the request to be OK for `@login_required`.
  It is often used for UI logins from browser.
  It will store session cookies to the browser and use them to auth later.
  So **you need to login only once** and the session will keep for a time.
- Using `request_loader` will also be OK with `@login_required`.
  But it is often used with api_key or basic auth.
  For example used by other apps to interact with your flask app.
  There will be no session cookies,
  so **you need to provide the auth info every time** you send request.

With both `user_loader` and `request_loader`,
now you got **2 ways of auth for the same api**,
**protected by `@login_required`**,
and **with `current_user` usable**,
which is really smart.

Answer (score 1):

To verify users with Flask-Login's session_id for frontend requests through Angular, you must set the `withCredentials` configuration flag to `true`.

That is, if you are using Angular's `$http.post(url,data [,config])` or `$http.get(url [,config])`, make sure the `config` object contains the property `withCredentials` set to true. This will instruct the browser to use its cookies in the same way it would for a full-on page visit.

For example,

```
$http.post('/api/login',{username:'myusername',password:'mypassword'},{withCredentials:true})
```

will `post` the data `{username:'myusername',password:'mypassword'}` to your site/app's `/api/login` route and, if you're using Flask-Login and are logged in, Flask will know.

You can set this behavior for **all** `$http` service requests by setting

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials=true
```

somewhere in your app. Currently, I have that line of code in my `app.config` block, which seems appropriate to me:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  });
```

(Since this post is about Flask, folks may want to send form data through Angular in such a way that it can be found in `request.form`, which has a similar solution, fyi.)

Comment: Hi Zach... Yes.  This will work when you have a request loader.  However, note that the username and password will be visible to everyone who has access to the codebase (when you host the website...that's basically the whole world)... So this could pose a security risk (possibly).

Comment: Hi @galeej , can you please say more about this? My example is totally bizarre, I admit - I showed passing credentials during a login, which is one of the only times it doesn't make much sense to pass credentials; the credentials sent by Angular with this configuration are simply your session_id, as it is cookie-formatted by Flask-login. So email and password are not, in fact, sent in arbitrary $http calls. All that being said, I'm still curious why you suspect anyone with access to the "codebase" would have access to any user information and, furthermore, why "the whole world" would have that

Comment: I dont know how I missed this.  I meant that when you hard code this onto the front end, the username and password will be exposed (as compared to using user loader).  If you are using only APIs to your customers, then go for request loader.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This was the reason it wasn't working for me! Although I am using React as opposed to Angular