# what's the proper way to use request_loader in flask-login

Tags: python, authentication, flask, jwt, flask-login

I would like to have the following authentication scheme

- a login page where the user login with email and password, the flask server then returns a JWT token
- for later API access, the user has to provide the JWT token in the authorization header

However, I don't fully understand the inner working of flask-login. My preliminary understanding is that

- After user submits the password, we call `login_user` and flask-login creates a session to store user information (maybe `user_id`?)
- Next time a request comes, authentication is done before processing the request if `login_required` decorator is used

I thought only `request_loader` would be needed if JWT authentication is used because all we need to do is check every request header. But if only the `request_loader` function is provided (see code below), exception is thrown.

> Exception: No user_loader has been installed for this LoginManager. Add one with the 'LoginManager.user_loader' decorator.

More specifically, my questions are

1. what are the roles played by `user_loader` and `request_loader` if we are to use JWT authentication?
2. when are `user_loader` and `request_loader` being called, if both of them are provided?
3. why do we still need `user_loader` if `request_loader` is provided?

Here are my implementation of these two loaders

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user_from_request(request):

    auth_str = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    token = auth_str.split(' ')[1] if auth_str else ''
    if token:
        user_id = User.decode_token(token)
        user = User.query.get(int(user_id))
        if user:
            return user
    return None
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Flask-Login's request\_loader related to user\_loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483026/how-is-flask-logins-request-loader-related-to-user-loader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice the exception of

> Exception: No user_loader has been installed for this LoginManager. Add one with the 'LoginManager.user_loader' decorator.

is caused by the the `logout` handler given as follows

```
@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('You have logged out.')
    return redirect(url_for('home.index'))
```

The reason is that flask-login needs to figure out which user to log out, which is done by calling a `utils._get_user()` function, which calls `login_manager._load_user()`, which further calls `login_manager.reload_user()`, and `reload_user()` will try to call the function `login_manager.user_loader` decorates which converts the `user_id` stored in the session to a user instance.

Thus as a workaround, one can define this function `login_manager.user_loader` decorates. I still think it's kind of a bug because the request alone is able to determine the user instance already, isn't that the purpose of `request_loader`?